# Why is "permission denied" when I try to connect to NameNode and DataNode in Hadoop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, ssh

I'm new to Hadoop and have been trying to implement a multi-node cluster using two Ubuntu virtual machines in Oracle VirtualBox. One machine is a "master" and the other is a "slave".

I have managed to get password-less SSH between the two machines working. I tested this out by typing "ssh [MachineUsername]" after the public keys were generated, and on both ends, it just logged me into that other machine automatically without asking for a password or throwing up any kind of error; from my end, it seemed to work perfectly.

However, when I tried to run sbin/start-all.sh on the master VM, it returned the following error message:

```
Starting namenodes on [bda-VirtualBox]
bda-VirtualBox: root@bda-virtualbox: Permission denied (publickey, password).
```

The same error cropped up for datanodes and secondary namenodes as well.

I looked around the internet, and I initially thought from internet research that the issue might have been something to do with how I initialised the encryption keys. Following the instructions of an internet tutorial on how to solve the "permission denied" issue (https://dzone.com/articles/resolving-permission-issue-in-multi-node-hadoop-cl), I then implemented my encryption keys within each VM using the following command line commands:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ” -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

In order to enable SSH between the two VMs, I also implemented the following line of code in each VM individually:

```
$ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub [OtherVMUsername]
```

When I tried this, the same error was still returned, so following the instructions of the above tutorial further, I altered the settings of the sshd_config file in each VM such that:

- PubKeyAuthentication was uncommented and valued "yes"
- PasswordAuthentication was uncommented and valued "yes"
- UsePAM was uncommented and valued "no"

I then restarted the SSH of each VM and tried again (the command was as follows):

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

I restarted the cluster using the same start-all.sh file as before, but the same error was still returned.

For clarity, I did initialise the namenode before launching start-all.sh in all cases using the command:

```
./hadoop namenode -format
```

And my namenode user, datanode user, secondary namenode user, yarn resource manager user and yarn node manager user are all set to root within hdfs-env.sh in both VMs.

The firewall is also disabled in both.

However, the error didn't seem to go away regardless of what I did with the SSH settings.

Does anyone know where I might be going wrong, as I'll admit to being a little confused?